# Im getting key error after resetting index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, jupyter-notebook, keyerror

So I removed some rows from a dataframe and then ran a isnull function on one of its columns. This created a bool array of true/false values. the array created has has a index with missing indexes from the rows that I removed.(eg 0,2,4,5 vs 0,1,2,3 if I didnt remove any rows) Because of this I used the reset_index() function on my bool array to reset the index to not skip values.

the problem is that once I reset the index i get a key error once I try to index the bool array i created. Note:When I show the array it show the array without any missing values in the index.

[image: true/false bool array with index reset]

this is the code I used to create and re-index my bool array. If I index 0 i get a key error and it seems any other value I use I get this error too.

```
GenderNullBool=df['Q2: GENDER'].isnull().reset_index()
GenderNullBool[0]
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this key error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please start by *looking more carefully at the data*. "Because of this I used the reset_index() function on my bool array to reset the index to not skip values." Okay, but this clearly didn't do what you expected. "When I show the array it show the array without any missing values in the index." That's clearly not true. Notice how, in the screenshot, it says that the DataFrame has 2460 rows, and that the last row is 2459, but the last value in the `index` column is 2478?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, thats a mistake, the dataframe expects a column name in its bracket, which it refers to "KEY", and in your case since there is no column named "0", it raises key error.

If you want to access the first value you can use slicing on dataframe.
like: `GenderNullBool[:1]`
or alternatively `GenderNullBool.head(1)`

Comment: One more thing, that I think can help, using `GenderNullBool=df['Q2: GENDER'].isnull().reset_index()`, will only give you the boolean values of "Q2: GENDER" in GenderNullBool,  
if you just want the column values to change use have to specify like `df["Q2: GENDER"] = df['Q2: GENDER'].isnull().reset_index()'`, and you even don't need reset index here.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean. Is there a way to reset index without adding a new column

Comment: `df["Q2: GENDER"] = df['Q2: GENDER'].isnull().reset_index()`
this won't add new column, it will modify the existing one.

Please upvote if i was of any help 

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **index** a `data frame` similar to how you would **index** an `array`, you need to use `iloc[]`:

```
GenderNullBool=df['Q2: GENDER'].isnull().reset_index()
GenderNullBool.iloc[0]
```

**Note** that if you don't want to insert index into data frame columns. You're going to want to use the `drop=True` argument in your `reset_index()` call. This resets the index to the default integer index. The call would look like this:

```
GenderNullBool=df['Q2: GENDER'].isnull().reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you want to read more on indexing and selecting data you can read the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse your following two lines step by step

```py
GenderNullBool = df['Q2: GENDER'].isnull().reset_index()
GenderNullBool[0]
```

- `df['Q2: GENDER']` selects a column from dataframe, it is a Series
- `df['Q2: GENDER'].isnull()` returns a boolean Series
- `df['Q2: GENDER'].isnull().reset_index()` resets the index to a new column, so it is a DataFrame

When you call `GenderNullBool[0]`, you are indexing `[0]` to a DataFrame just like what you do `df['Q2: GENDER']`.

Therefore, `0` should be in the columns of `GenderNullBool` else it throws key error.

If you want to select the first row from the dataframe, you can do

```
GenderNullBool.loc[0]    # if index is RangeIndex(start=0, stop=x, step=1)
# or
GenderNullBool.iloc[0]
```